# Как убрать padding с #Subheader / WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Добрый день уважаемые. При создании новой страници в WP когда пишу заголовок страници инлайново добавляется к id=Subheader padding кто-то знает как его можно убрать, я так понимаю что это где-то из админки делается ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В style.css своей темы добавьте

```
#Subheader {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Так вы перекроете стиль элемента, который добавляет скрипт.